# Xcode Linked Framework Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I keep getting the following error, even when following the instructions on the couchbase website and trying several different changes.

```
Ld /Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Resources-
gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/Resources.app/Resources normal x86_64
cd /Users/mpschmidt/Documents/Code/Resources
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/
usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/mpschmidt/Library
/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Products
/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -    
F/Users/mpschmidt/Documents/Code/Resources -filelist /Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer
/Xcode/DerivedData/
Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Intermediates/Resources.build/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Resources.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Resources.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 
-Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version 
-Xlinker 2 -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Intermediates/Resources.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Resources.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Resources.swiftmodule -framework CouchbaseLiteListener -framework CouchbaseLite -lz -lsqlite3 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework CFNetwork 
-Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Intermediates/Resources.build/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Resources.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Resources_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mpschmidt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Resources-gawdqzaqxvjlymbelkixzqnweita/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/
Resources.app/Resources

ld: framework not found CouchbaseLite
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the error here? I uploaded the frameworks, and followed all the instructions on http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/training/build-first-ios-app/create-new-project/index.html . By the way, I am trying to use it with swift, and I have instructions on how to do that, but I am not sure if that matters in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to link CouchbaseLite as a dynamic framework (`-framework CouchbaseLite`) but it's actually static.

My guess is that you accidentally downloaded the Mac version (which is a dynamic framework), not the iOS version.